# Deploy objects on mid air stage only once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm very new to this and I'm working on a simple AR app with Unity and Vuforia. When I tap the screen it places the object(which is good ofc), then when I tap again it would re-place the object. I want it to only deploy once and doesn't re-place when I tap multiple times. Is there a way to do this? I found the DeployStageOnce.cs script, but I don't think it works anymore.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post some code sample like what you have tried